# How to set minimum IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET version in React Native using Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, podfile

Got the following error after running `npx expo run:ios` this morning, not sure what's changed was fine yesterday.

> /Users/{me}/Desktop/Development/{my-project}/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of
> supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.0.99. (in target
> 'libaom' from project 'Pods')
> /Users/{me}/Desktop/Development/{my-project}/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of
> supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.0.99. (in target
> 'SDWebImage' from project 'Pods')
> /Users/{me}/Desktop/Development/{my-project}/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of
> supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.0.99. (in target
> 'FirebaseCoreExtension' from project 'Pods')
> /Users/{me}/Desktop/Development/{my-project}/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of
> supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.0.99. (in target
> 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
> /Users/{me}/Desktop/Development/{my-project}/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of
> supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.0.99. (in target
> 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop' from project 'Pods')
> /Users/{me}/Desktop/Development/{my-project}/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of
> supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.0.99. (in target
> 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')

Reading through the expo.dev documentation [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/). I've set my iOS deployment version to be 13.0 in my `app.json` file as per the below;

```
"plugins": [
      "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin",
      [
        "@stripe/stripe-react-native",
        {
          "merchantIdentifier": "XXXXXXXXXX",
          "enableGooglePay": false
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
```

I've deleted my .ios & .android folders re-run `npx expo prebuild` and then `npx expo run:ios` but still receiving the same issue.

### package.json

```
"@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.6.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.6.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.6.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.6.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^18.6.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.6.2",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.28.0",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.20.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image": "~1.3.5",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-instantsearch-core": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^12.1.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0"
```

### UPDATE

So turns out that I don't need to specify `"deploymentTarget": "13.0"` in app.json as when running npx expo prebuild when the native files are generated the podfile sets the deploymentTarget to 13 if the key is missing in the app.json file.

### PODFILE:

```
platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.0'
```

however, this is not being forced in the pods. For example going into XCode and checking I can see it's still 11.0.

[image]

Comment: From the error log, it seems to be related to Firebase/Google libraries. Did you upgrade any? Can you share your package.json files so we can see which dependencies you have and their versions?

Comment: @tomerpacific I've not updated them intentionally, added package.json in the question

Comment: 1) Consider directly configuring the iOS deployment target in the ios/Podfile. To add or update the deployment target, open iOS/Podfile:  platform: '13.0', iOS

 2) It appears that your package contains multiple entries for expo-build-properties.JSON. These can be combined into a single entry.

4) Reinstall the dependencies and empty the caches:
rm -rf node_modules
npm install npx pod-install rm -rf ios/Pods

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm facing the same RN :(

Comment: I've started getting this error today, I'm scratching my head to figure out what's up. I'm seeing messages related to Google sign-in which would tally with the observation from  @tomerpacific

Comment: @DavidCarboni For some reason moving my project file to the desktop solved this issue, I'm not sure how - so doing some deeper digging so I can upload the answer.